# Are there any alternatives for Android Market statistics?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

I am having some issues with Android market statistics as they have not been updated for more than a week. This issue seems to be reoccurring with no solution from Google. Are there any alternatives that I can use for my app to get statistics like how many people are using it, what kind of mobile phones and/or Android version are being used.

Will Google analytics do the job? Is there any other stat service dedicated for mobile phones only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see what Google Analytics can to on mobile devices, take a look at the [Google Code page for Google Analytics](http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/android/).  A listing of the dimensions and metrics available with Google Analytics is available [here](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDimensionsMetrics.html).  If you are looking for a free service, I think this is the one you want to use.

If you are more interested in pay services, there are plenty.  Here are a few from a [simple google search](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mobile%20analytics):

1. [WebTrends](http://webtrends.com/products/analytics/mobile/)
2. [Bango](http://bango.com/mobileanalytics/)
3. [Localytics](http://www.localytics.com/)